# Android Studio, App engine; where to add JPA, Data Access Layer, Business Layer in Generated Code

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

following:
[How does an Android and App Engine Actually communicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814479/how-does-an-android-and-app-engine-actually-communicate)

and 
steps: (AS 0.4.0) New Project, Generate App Engine, Generate Client Libraries

I get a file tree like (lots of directories aren't shown) :

```
d20
+src ... (MainActivity class)

d20-appengine
+src
  +java
    +com.example.d20 (package)
       (classes like DeviceInfo, DeviceInfoEndpoint, MessageData, MessageEndpoint)

d20-endpoints
+src
  +endpoint-src
   +java
    +com.example.d20 (package)
     + deviceinfoendpoint (package)
      (Classes like Deviceinfoendpoint)
      + model
        (Classes like DeviceInfo)
     + messageEndpoint
      (Classes like MessageEndpoint)
       + model
         (Classes like Key, MessageData)

  +main
   + java
    + com.example.d20 (package)
      (Classes like RegisterActivity, GCMIntent Service)
```

Question:
  following the idea that Business logic layer => Data access layer => JPA Plain Old Java
what is what from the above source and where do new classes go?

From reading the source for a couple days I guess the "model" packages in each type of endpoint package hold the JPA.  And the Data Access Layer are the Classes in the two endpoint packages (deviceinfoendpoint, and messageEndpoint)

And so I guess the Business logic layer is in GCMIntentServices    (registers device, unregisters, handles messages from GCM)

Is that an accurate understanding of the pieces?

And so if I'd like to add an endpoint that accesses a Datastore should I follow this organization  (note all classes in Model packages extend json  example: public final class Key extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson - is that the recommended way to model or is there something more 'googly')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your question but I'll give some input on how to create an endpoint that interacts with the datastore.

For most circumstances you don't need to change any of the code in the d20-endpoints section - this is generated for you when you click Generate Client Libraries and is used to communicate from your android app to the App Engine Datastore.

To make a new endpoint add an Entity(like DeviceInfo) to d20-appengine. If it's your first one I would copy the file DeviceInfo and edit it to fit your needs. So for this example the entity were creating is going to be called Doctor. So include an id (doctorName), fields(doctorAddress,doctorAge,yearsInPractice) and all the getters and setters. Then click on Doctors -> Tools->Google cloud tools -> generate endpoint

The DoctorEndpoint what is called to insert,retrieve and remove the entity from the datastore. You edit this DoctorEndpoint if you want to add special queries.

Update Google App engine by clicking maven appengine:update. Wait for it to finish. Then click on d20-appengine -> Tools->Google cloud tools -> Generate Client Libraries. Wait for it to finish. I usually do this a second time but not sure if it is necessary appengine:update.

The d20-endpoints section will be generated for you automatically and you can access it from your android app by calling something like this in your android app (make sure it is a doInBackground task)

```
private class taskGetDoctor extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {


            Doctorendpoint.Builder builder = new Doctorendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new JacksonFactory(),null);
            builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);
            Doctorendpoint endpoint = builder.build();
            Doctor doctor = endpoint.getDoctors("drJohn").execute(); 

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks a ton!  Curious about the Doctorendpoint.Builder reference. I don't understand the syntax (Class.Builder)...  Compiler wont get past it.  Do I need to implement Builder in Doctorendpoint or is it inherited from somewhere?

Comment: This is what I import 
import com.path.youprojectname.doctorendpoint.Doctorendpoint;

It is coming from the Project-endpoints class. I didn't add anything to the code

Not sure if this helps or not... if you want me to try and explain more I can

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the explanation for sure.  Here's what's happening: New Project, Generate App Engine, added Doctor class, selected and Generate Endpoint (DoctorEndpoint appears in AppEngine tree beside Doctor), then Generate Client Libraries and appengine:update

Problem is I'm not seeing what you report, which is more code generated and appearing in D20-endpoints tree - nothing new showed up there.

Comment: Also, I also don't really understand what the files that are generated are for.  I get creating a @Entity bean, I get Create Endpoint, but what is the file that's (supposed to be) generated in the d20-endpoints tree?  I suppose that's where the methods are that I use to with my Activities to access the data on the server.. is that so?  THANKS!

Comment: NOTE: A Warning dialog box appears when I run Generate Client Libraries:  it says "Could not find associated Android library module (d20-endpoints), skipping copying of client libraries into Android"  and when I click OK it goes ahead and does stuff, but maybe not what you're describing (d20-endpoints is the wrong name, its D20-endpoints)...

Comment: UPDATE: Ohhhh.... the new code (including the Builder method) are stashed in DB20-appengine/google_generated/doctorendpoint/lib-expanded-source/sic/example/d20/doctorendpoint/
with a subdir for "model" and Doctorendpoint.java

so that's right...

Comment: There should be new code in  DB20-endpoints/src/endpoint-src/java/com/d20

Comment: there seems to be some bug in Studio regarding copying generated code into the app-endpoints tree related to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=4&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=64537

Comment: tried this 8 times different ways,  Studio 0.4.2 1/9/14 build is not seeing the target endpoint tree so the client endpoint code never gets generated there.    I'm going to try to copy the generate code by hand from google_generated...

Comment: Google developer commented on the report and confirmed the bug.  Possible workaround is:


After Generate Client Libraries, the code in 
app-AppEngine/google_generated/<BeanName>endpoint/lib-expanded-source/<package>/<BeanName>endpoint/ 

{there are three .java files; <BeanName>endpoint.java, <BeanName>endpointRequest.java, and <BeanName>endpointRequestInitializer.java,
additionally there is a "model" folder with <BeanName>.java and CollectionResponse<BeanName>.java
}

are in fact the client libraries and if I copy them by hand into 
app-endpoints/src/endpoint-src/java/<package>